# Erroring getting image size from javascript

Tags: javascript, image-size

I am trying to get the size of the image via javascript and I keep getting undefined.

```
var s = '/images/clouds.png';
console.log(s.naturalWidth);
```

Keep getting undefined.

Comment: That's because `s` is not an image but text. You need to actually create an `Image` object first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create an image object in for example HTML:

```
<img id="randomImg" src="/images/clouds.png" />
```

afterwards you can retrieve the object in javascript:

```
var s = document.getElementById("randomImg");
```

And then you can ask for the size

Comment: This only works once the image has loaded; `s.naturalWidth` will not yield the correct result until after.

Comment: I have never had problems with this before, So I think unless your code is really poorly performing it should not be a problem.

Comment: Wrong. You can easily try it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/hsLhjcm2/ When you change the image size, you will reliably get `0` every time. Plus your solution requires showing the image on the page, which is unnecessary and might not be desired at all, at least before its size is known.

Comment: Well everything you are saying was not requested in the question and seems to me you are just trying to break down my answer. And everything you list here can be easily avoided because it's a piece of cake to hide an image if he wanted that(which was never stated) and beside unlike you I would never just use images from the internet, I would always get the images I want and either remake them myself (so they are way smaller and I don't have to worry about copyrighted images) or at least use a cropping tool so your image is only a few bytes big. So to me my performance statement stays.

Comment: If you're talking about hotlinking images from other servers versus using your own, these own images are still downloaded by the browser when the page is first visited, so to get their dimensions one needs to wait until that's done or it won't work. You can claim otherwise all you like but it doesn't make it true. And small images are usually a few *kilo*bytes big.

Comment: Well then I suggest we leave it at this, I still stand by my case that what you are saying is not requested nor needed and you stay with yours that my code could be made better. Don't think anything else is going to change from continuing this conversation, so best of luck and keep trying to help others :).

Comment: You could of course overcome your willful ignorance and spite and accept that getting the size of a not yet loaded image will not work, as demonstrated by code I provided. If your method reliably works, surely you can prove it?

Comment: I have tested it and you are indeed correct you will need the onLoad method. Reason that it did work for me is that as stated before I will always remake the images and give them the desired height and width that I want. So I just saw that (as I believe is the best way to do) I would always set the correct height and width already in my <img /> element and thus I was always able to retrieve it.But indeed if you get random images of the internet without height and with tags you would indeed always get 0. So you can put the code in a simple onLoad and everything will be okay.

Comment: I don't think it's related to stating `<img width="..." height="...">`, which are completely unrelated to the **natural**Width of the image (because their intended use is to *change* the dimensions, where as *natural*Width gives the, well, natural width). The reason the browser shows the proper size is because the image is still cached. That's why I'm using a random width, to ensure the image has to be loaded first.

Comment: Ye, I don't think I ever stated that I used naturalWidth in my programs from which I adapted my answer. I only once needed the width of an image when I was working with javascript and that was the clientWidth in which case the width and height tag of the image work perfect, it was a specific case with only an image on the page so clientWidth worked for it. But anyway case is you were right about the onLoad part, so if you wrap my javascript code in an onLoad it would work. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You said `I would always set the correct height and width already in my <img /> element and thus I was always able to retrieve it.` which is wrong.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hsLhjcm2/3/ is it? Seems like I set height and width tags and I get them.

Comment: I see, so you thought `naturalWidth` would work exactly like `clientWidth`. Ok then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an actual `Image`, then wait until it has successfully loaded:

```js
var s = new Image();
s.onload = function() {
  console.log("after image has loaded:", this.naturalWidth);
}
var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 200;
s.src = `http://via.placeholder.com/${width}x300`;
console.log("not loaded yet:", s.naturalWidth);
```